# Самоподписанные сертификаты как их правильно сделать

Tags: java, сертификат

есть такая прога для изготовления самоподписанных сертификатов http://portecle.sourceforge.net . если с помощью её создаю - создаётся нормально, в FF добавляю исключение - и можно работать... раньше можно было и в хроме добавить сертификат, экспортированный это же прогой из ей же созданноного jks файла. но хром стал о нас заботиться слишком сильно .... ему потребовалось subjectAltName , а эта прога его вставить не может. пытался создать в openssl, и импортировать при промощи portecle в jks, все проходит , но FF не может понять такой сертификат с сервера. Даже если создаю без subjectAltName. Получается есть какая-то разница, но в чём? и как добиться нужного?

пробую создать сертификат с помощью http://xca.sourceforge.net/ . всё создаётся, экпортирую в разные форматы, их импортирую в portecle, всё проходит без ошибок, но FF не хочет/не может воспринимать их с сервера, пишет - нет доступной информации....

Comment: Вопрос не до конца понятен, ссылка не работает

Comment: @labris ссылку поправил, а что не понятно?